# What will be big O complexity for this loop?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I am not able to understand time complexity of this for loop. 
While outer loop is O(n) the inner loop jumps certain calculation. How to find the complexity?

```
public void function(n) {
                    for(int i = 1; i< n; i++) {
                        for(int j =     1; j <= n;  j += i) {
                                System.out.println("*")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "jumps certain calculation"? The number of iterations of the inner loop depends strictly on the value of `n`.

Comment: Sorry I just made an edit for inner loop. where increment on j is now function of i

Comment: The time complexity of your program is not defined because your program never terminates.

Comment: Correct. Let me edit. Changed i = 0 to i = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loopnever stopped for $n \geq 1$ as for the first time `i = 0` and `j += i` never increased the value of `j`. If we suppose `i` will be started from `1`, for `i = 1` the inner loop will be iterated $n$ times. for `i = 2` as value of `j` is increased by step size `2`, the number of iterations of the inner loop is $\frac{n}{2}$. Hence, the computation cost of the program is $\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{i} = n \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i} = \Theta(n\log(n))$.